# AjaxFileUpload postback false

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, asp.net-ajax, postback

i am using `AjaxFileUpload` in `ASP.NET 4.0` website. The problem is that when i upload a file its `UploadComplete` fires which causes a postback to page. on every `postback` caused by `AjaxFileUpload` the `Ispostback` property is `False` which should be `True`. What is the reason. I checked it in the `updatePanel` and without it. It has no affect at it. Here is the

```
  <ajax:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ContextKeys="fred" 
     AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" MaximumNumberOfFiles="3" runat="server" 
        OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To detect postback from the AjaxFileUpload use this control's property: `AjaxFileUpload.IsInFileUploadPostBack`. The `IsPostBack` property doesn't works because this control submits not to the same page where is was rendered but to hidden frame instead so it's the first time for frame it loading on server. See more in AjaxControlToolkit sources: [AjaxControlToolkit AjaxFileUpload](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2a6dc6854e0#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx.cs)

Comment: A couple of years using all sort of things to deal with it... and this property exists... Thank you so much for taking away this pain

Answer (score 0):

Its a direct solution code of this problem

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
        // check if postback came through AjaxFileUpload control
        if (AjaxFileUpload1.IsInFileUploadPostBack)
        {
            // do for ajax file upload partial postback request
        }
        else
        { 
            // do for normal page request
        }
}
```